# Most Efficient Method of Reading a TSV file to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am attempting to open a gzip file and store the uncompressed TSV file into a dataframe. When I try to do this there is a memory error due at 'pd.read_table()' or 'pd.read_csv()' part. I have tried both methods. Unfortunately, the file I am trying to open is greater than 6 GB.

Code example:

```
for i in tqdm(filelist[24:25]):
fin = gzip.open(i)
df = pd.read_table(fin ,sep='\t',lineterminator='\n', names=['ngram', 'year','match_count', 'volume_count'])
```

I get the following error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.00 MiB for an array with shape (131072,) and data type int64
```

**Is there a more memory-efficient way of reading a large TSV file into a dataframe?**

Comment: 6GB, and I'm assuming that's the compressed size, so depending upon compression you might be looking at 10-100GB of data.. If you want to hold all that data at once, you need more RAM, not much else. Otherwise you can chunk process the data.

Comment: How do you fit 10 gallons in a 1 gallon bucket? One gallon at a time...

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: `int64` is a bit overkill for a year, pick suitable data types at least